# Guild is not defined (ReferenceError)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I get an error while executing this code:

```
const now = new Date();

bot.on("guildMemberRemove", member => {

    console.log(member.user.username + ' left from a Server at ' +  now + `Just watch the logs on the server`)

  });
```

Any help there? :-)
Greetings and have a nice day!

Edit:

```
    const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const bot = new commando.Client();
const now = new Date();
bot.registry.registerGroup('random', 'Random');
bot.registry.registerGroup('reply', 'Reply');
bot.registry.registerDefaults();
bot.registry.registerCommandsIn(__dirname + "/commands")


bot.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Bot has started, with ${bot.users.size} users, in ${bot.channels.size} channels of ${bot.guilds.size} guilds.`);
  bot.user.setActivity(`Serving ${bot.guilds.size} servers`);
});

bot.on("guildCreate", guild => {
  console.log(`New guild joined: ${guild.name} (id: ${guild.id}). This guild has ${guild.memberCount} members!`);
  bot.user.setActivity(`Serving ${bot.guilds.size} servers`);
});


bot.on("guildMemberRemove", member => {

    console.log(member.user.username + ' left from a Server at ' +  now + `Just watch the logs on the server ${guild.name}`)

  });

bot.on("message", async message => {

  var optionsGreetings = ["Hellouu", "Heyy", "Hi there", "How ya doing?", "LETS GO DUDE"];
  var optionsHowAreYou = ["I had a bad day, whats about you, how are you doing?", "Robots have no feelings but whats about you?", "I am pretty good!", "I am doing fine, thanks, and you?", "Im good, how are you?", ];
  var responseGreetings = optionsGreetings[Math.floor(Math.random()*optionsGreetings.length)];
  var responseHowAreYou = optionsHowAreYou[Math.floor(Math.random()*optionsHowAreYou.length)];

  //Hello responses
  if(message.content == 'Hello') {
    message.channel.send(responseGreetings)
  }

  if(message.content == 'Hi') {
    message.channel.send(responseGreetings)
  }

  if(message.content == 'Hey') {
    message.channel.send(responseGreetings)
  }

  //How Are you? Responses
  if(message.content == 'How are you?') {
    message.channel.send(responseHowAreYou)
  }

  if(message.content == 'ping') {
    message.reply(`API Latency is ${Math.round(bot.ping)}ms`)
  }

  if(message.content == 'why?') {
    message.channel.send(`Because!`)
  }

  if(message.content == 'why') {
    message.channel.send(`Because!`)
  }

  if(message.content == 'Why?') {
    message.channel.send(`Because!`)
  }

  if(message.content == 'Why') {
    message.channel.send(`Because!`)
  }

});




bot.login('MY_TOKEN')
```

Probably a ton of shit in there but, hey who cares?

My error that ocurs is: ReferneceError: Guild is not Defined
  at ...
  at ...

Ton of things I cant copy, I dont wanna type it in by hand, hope this helps you to understand my code!

Comment: Can you show the exact stack trace?. `guild` isn't present in that code, so post the code where the error is happening.

Comment: whats the error? can you please post the error as well as the code that the error says is erroring?

Comment: Mhh, this should be the lines where its happening, you know hwat? As a newbie I maybe post the whole code, there just a few lines

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this in your edit:

```
bot.on("guildMemberRemove", member => {
  console.log(member.user.username + ' left from a Server at ' +  now + `Just watch the logs on the server ${guild.name}`)
});
```

You're using `guild.name` but in that function, you only pass `member` in the arguments.
In the first code you posted you didn't write that, but in the second one you did, so try replacing `guild.name` with `member.guild.name`